# Magento 2.3.5 Custom Layout Update

Tags: cms-pages, magento2.3.5, custom-layout-update

I need to use a layout update for cms page.

I've created a file called cms_page_view_selectable_home_HomePageBlocks.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
      <container name="main-content-outer" before="main.content">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="tm_slider">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">tm_slider</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="tm_category_banner_cms">
                 <arguments>
                      <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">tm_category_banner_cms</argument>
                 </arguments>
           </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="tm_subbanner_CMS">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">tm_subbanner_CMS</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
           <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="tm_special_cms">
                <arguments>
                     <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">tm_special_cms</argument>
                </arguments>
             </block>
             <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="tm_homepage_service_cms">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">tm_homepage_service_cms</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block> 
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="tm_Products_CMS">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">tm_Products_CMS</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>  
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="tm_Singlebanner_CMS">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">tm_Singlebanner_CMS</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="tm_manufacture">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">tm_manufacture</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="tm_blog">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">tm_blog</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
      </container>
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

I'm able to selecte it in CMS Page Edit Form, but nothing shows in frontend.

There is something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT IS A BUG

found the solution at:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/53c78d534063efa1d8275e27f9cd019dfd9000dc